# Parametrization and area of surface

Tags: surfaces, surface-integrals, parametrization

I have not grasped the way to solve these kinds of problems yet. I need to parametrize the surface and find its area: $S:x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ with $z \ge\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{3}$.

I have already parametrized the surface of the sphere this way:

$S:(x,y,z)=(2\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta},2\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta}, 2\cos{\phi})$

But how do I find the limits of integration to find the area of the part of the sphere enclosed by $z \ge\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{3}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z \ge\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{3}\\
2\cos\phi \ge\frac{2\sin\phi}{3}\\
3 \ge\tan\phi\\
\phi \le\tan^{-1} 3$

Comment: The answer on my textbook for the area is $4 \pi$. This $\tan^{-1} {3}$ is kinda bothering me.

Comment: There must be a typo on my textbook, I have just tested the surface $z \ge \sqrt \frac{x^2+y^2}{3}$ and it lead to the correct answer. Thanks :D

Comment: Are you sure that $z = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{3}$ and not $z =\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{3}}?  4\pi$ would make more sense if that were the case.